# Filter does not get applied on change of input text: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate, react-table

I am trying to implement a search filter that searches the characters across the entire table. The filter is not getting applied correctly. I am using react-table for the data grid. I am firing change handler on every input and then using filter to filter out the data. Unable to achieve the same

Help would be appreciated.

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-hooks-tblde

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Input } from "semantic-ui-react";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      filteredData: [],
      columns: [],
      searchInput: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.getColumns();
  }

  getColumns = () => {
    let columns = [
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "status"
      },
      {
        Header: "Visits",
        accessor: "visits"
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  };

  getData = () => {
    let data = [
      { firstName: "aaaaa", status: "Pending", visits: 155 },
      { firstName: "aabFaa", status: "Pending", visits: 155 },
      { firstName: "adaAAaaa", status: "Approved", visits: 1785 },
      { firstName: "aAaaaa", status: "Approved", visits: 175 },
      { firstName: "adaSaaa", status: "Cancelled", visits: 165 },
      { firstName: "aasaaa", status: "Cancelled", visits: 157 },
      { firstName: "aweaaaaaewea", status: "Approved", visits: 153 },
      { firstName: "adaAAadsdweaa", status: "Approved", visits: 17585 },
      { firstName: "aAaaaa", status: "Approved", visits: 175 },
      { firstName: "adadsdSaaa", status: "Cancelled", visits: 165 }
    ];
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ searchInput: event.target.value }, () => {
      this.globalSearch();
    });
  };

  globalSearch = () => {
    let { data, searchInput } = this.state;
    let filteredData = data.filter(value => {
      return (
        value.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.status.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.visits
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
    this.setState({ filteredData });
  };

  render() {
    let { data, columns, searchInput, filteredData } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Input
          size="large"
          name="searchInput"
          value={searchInput || ""}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          label="Search"
        />
        <ReactTable
          data={filteredData.length > 0 && filteredData ? filteredData : data}
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the filter? I see it working

Comment: No ! Try to give wrong input , say "bbbb" .It will give entire table data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here in your second approach error come from `handleSetData = data =>{this.setState({data});};` you are changing data state depending on filterdata that why your your data will disappear what you need to do is passing setting datafilter state like this :

`handleSetData = data => {this.setState({ filteredData: data });};`

and in
`ReactTable` u need to render `FilterData` or `data` like this:

`data={this.state.filteredData ? this.state.filteredData : data}`

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import GlobalSearchComponent from "./GlobalSearchComponent";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      filteredData: null,
      columns: [],
      searchInput: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.getColumns();
  }

  getColumns = () => {
    let columns = [
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "firstName",
        sortable: false,
        show: true,
        displayValue: " First Name"
      },
      {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "status",
        sortable: false,
        show: true,
        displayValue: "Status "
      },
      {
        Header: "Visits",
        accessor: "visits",
        sortable: false,
        show: true,
        displayValue: " Visits "
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  };

  getData = () => {
    let data = [
      { firstName: "aaaaa", status: "Pending", visits: 155 },
      { firstName: "aabFaa", status: "Pending", visits: 155 },
      { firstName: "adaAAaaa", status: "Approved", visits: 1785 },
      { firstName: "aAaaaa", status: "Approved", visits: 175 },
      { firstName: "adaSaaa", status: "Cancelled", visits: 165 },
      { firstName: "aasaaa", status: "Cancelled", visits: 157 },
      { firstName: "aweaaaaaewea", status: "Approved", visits: 153 },
      { firstName: "adaAAadsdweaa", status: "Approved", visits: 17585 },
      { firstName: "aAaaaa", status: "Approved", visits: 175 },
      { firstName: "adadsdSaaa", status: "Cancelled", visits: 165 },
      { firstName: "dsdcdaaaaa", status: "Cancelled", visits: 157 },
      { firstName: "aaadvsaa", status: "Submitted", visits: 5153 },
      { firstName: "aaaaswea", status: "Pending", visits: 1555 },
      { firstName: "aaaaauwe", status: "Submitted", visits: 155 }
    ];
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  handleSetData = data => {
    this.setState({ filteredData: data });
  };

  render() {
    let { data, columns } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <GlobalSearchComponent
          data={this.state.data}
          handleSetData={this.handleSetData}
        />
        <ReactTable
          data={this.state.filteredData ? this.state.filteredData : data}
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

well the error is here `data={(filteredData.length > 0 && filteredData) ? filteredData: data}` so here if filteredData has 0 length it will return  data  array !
so what i did is check the input has some value :

```
  (filteredData.length > 0 && filteredData) || searchInput? filteredData: data
```

if input has value it will return filteredData wich is empty!

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Input } from "semantic-ui-react";
import ReactTable from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      filteredData: [],
      columns: [],
      searchInput: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
    this.getColumns();
  }

  getColumns = () => {
    let columns = [
      {
        Header: "First Name",
        accessor: "firstName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Status",
        accessor: "status"
      },
      {
        Header: "Visits",
        accessor: "visits"
      }
    ];
    this.setState({ columns });
  };

  getData = () => {
    let data = [
      { firstName: "aaaaa", status: "Pending", visits: 155 },
      { firstName: "aabFaa", status: "Pending", visits: 155 },
      { firstName: "adaAAaaa", status: "Approved", visits: 1785 },
      { firstName: "aAaaaa", status: "Approved", visits: 175 },
      { firstName: "adaSaaa", status: "Cancelled", visits: 165 },
      { firstName: "aasaaa", status: "Cancelled", visits: 157 },
      { firstName: "aweaaaaaewea", status: "Approved", visits: 153 },
      { firstName: "adaAAadsdweaa", status: "Approved", visits: 17585 },
      { firstName: "aAaaaa", status: "Approved", visits: 175 },
      { firstName: "adadsdSaaa", status: "Cancelled", visits: 165 }
    ];
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ searchInput: event.target.value }, () => {
      this.globalSearch();
    });
  };

  globalSearch = () => {
    let { data, searchInput } = this.state;
    let filteredData = data.filter(value => {
      return (
        value.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.status.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()) ||
        value.visits
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
      );
    });
    this.setState({ filteredData: filteredData });
  };

  render() {
    let { data, columns, searchInput, filteredData } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Input
          size="large"
          name="searchInput"
          value={searchInput || ""}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          label="Search"
        />
        <ReactTable
          data={
            (filteredData.length > 0 && filteredData) || searchInput
              ? filteredData
              : data
          }
          columns={columns}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Now I have exported the search filter as a separate component, passing the data between compoents. Filter seems broken after I delete characters : https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-gould-kw9iq

Comment: check below answer !

Comment: That did work! Now what if I want to integrate it with a column level search filter, where based on each click I make a server call than then it returns me the data , In this case how would the state object and passing data look like ? Here also I will maintain a separate column level search component that will be attached to each column

Comment: U mean each column has it own search input?

Comment: yes correct! to each column I attach a say, ColumnSearchFilter . To this component what is the data that needs to be passed from App? Also while setting the state from this ColumnSearchFilter , would this affect the existing global search behavior?

Comment: yes absoultely ! But the thing is say I have typed Pending in global search and try to filter firstname, but column filter still applies on the overall data and not the previously filtered data?